# JQuery ajax POST non-standart key name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to give any name to data field in ajax call?
I want to have key `some_data[0].value` = `0`, but when I try

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost/test',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json', 
          data: {
               some_data[0].value : 0
          },
          success: function(data) {
...
             },
          error: function() { ... }
        });
```

it throws error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [` what is expected.

`some_data[0].value` is non valid name for js (it's basically considered as array), but is valid for HTTP parameter.

How to pass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property names that are not valid JavaScript identifiers (or numbers) can be included as strings.

Wrap it in a pair of `"` or `'`.

```
data: {
  "some_data[0].value" : 0
},
```

Comment: I thought that string should not be there. Thanks :) . Stupid question.